# Jmeter Junit request with FirefoxDriver

Tags: selenium, jmeter, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have an issue using latest firefox browser (50.1.0) with Selenium WebDriver and JMeter Combination. I am trying to fire up my test cases in firefox browser using Jmeter. I am using Selenium webdriver to build a JAR File and calling it in JMeter Junit Request. When I run my test case it fires up browse but get stuck at NEW TAB and doesn't call in my URL to play test scenario. IF I use an old Firefox browser (23) it works fine, but I am reading all articles for this issue, and they all say starting firefox 48 version, and for selenium 3.0 webdriver, we have to use gecko driver. I am using that as well. But still no use. here is my sample code:

```
public void test() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","c:\\Selenium\\FireFox_Driver\\geckodriver.exe");
/*  FirefoxProfile fp=new FirefoxProfile();
    DesiredCapabilities dcap=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    dcap.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.MARIONETTE, "c:\\Selenium\\FireFox_Driver\\geckodriver.exe");
    dcap.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, fp);
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(dcap);
*/      
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://gmail.com");
}
```

Any ideas on how to make use of latest browser? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Always look into *jmeter.log* file, it normally contains enough information to guess the failure reason. If you are not able to figure that out yourself - include essential log part into your question as Internet is full of "JMeter doesn't work" questions and no one can answer due to lack of details.

Let's start clean.

1. Download the [latest JMeter version](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) (3.1 as of now) and unpack it somewhere, i.e. in `C:\apps\jmeter` folder
2. Download the latest [Selenium Java client](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) (3.0.1 as of now). Put `client-combined-3.0.1-nodeps.jar` and everything which is in `lib` folder of the Selenium Java Client somewhere to [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (i.e. `C:\apps\jmeter\lib` folder)
3. This `DesiredCapabilities` are not required, according to [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver)

   > With Selenium 3.0 and later, you shouldn't need to do anything to use Marionette, as it's enabled by default.

My test code looks like:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\apps\\jmeter\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
log.info("Browser version:" +  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return navigator.userAgent"));
driver.get("http://gmail.com");
log.info("Page title: " + driver.getTitle());
```

And here is the output:

[image: Selenium JMeter JUnit Demo]

See [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) article for comprehensive information on JMeter and JUnit integration.

Comment: Bingo, I think you nailed it. I have copied Selenium-server standalone.jar file into Jmeter/Lib folder but not extracted the contents. After your response, I have extracted and copied Lib folder and client-combined..jar file and it now works as expected. Thank you so much. My problem is solved. I thought by just copying entire jar file would work but obviously not.